# git merge develop and master Issue

Tags: git, gitlab, git-merge, git-flow

I'm using Gitflow for my project. my `develop` branch is ahead of `master` branch by many commits in a while. But when I tried to merge master with develop by:

```
git merge develop
```

It says that `Already up to date`. Whats wrong with it or my operation?

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the results of these 3 commands: `git rev-parse master`, `git rev-parse develop`, `git merge-base master develop`. If the 2nd and 3rd commands have the same result, then `develop` is not ahead of `master`; you are truly up to date.

Comment: Side note, in Git Flow, you normally wouldn't ever merge `develop` into `master`. (But you would merge `master` into `develop`.)

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if you haven't pulled the develop branch changes recently. In this you can the one of the following things:

1. Pull remote develop changes to your local develop branch by:

   git checkout develop

   git pull develop

   git checkout master

   git merge develop
2. You can straightly merge origin/develop into local master branch by:

   git merge origin/develop

Comment: Thanks but I've already  pull and even clone. but problem is still exist even when I merged with `remotes/origin/develop`

Comment: Then, seems like your branch is up to date with the develop branch.
If you execute git log --oneline, you can check whether your master branch points to the same commit as develop or it's ahead/behind.

Comment: `git diff develop..master` command shows many differneces

Comment: This is fine. It says you've got differences between develop and master, but all of them may come from master.